# C++ pointer decleration

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

I do not understand what the difference between the two is:

`Double_node<Type *> *ptr = stack.list.head()`

and

`Double_node<Type *> ptr = stack.list.head()`

In both cases my intention is to declare a pointer which stores the values returned by `stack.list.head()`.

`stack.list.head()` returns a pointer to the head of the list.

Comment: The first one declares a pointer, the second one doesn't.

Comment: Down voted only because the answer could have easily be found by a google search.

Comment: Or by learning the language from a book. Y'know, guys? Books? Remember those?

Answer (score 2):

Well...

```
Double_node<Type *> *ptr = stack.list.head();
```

is declaring a variable `ptr` which is of type **pointer** (thanks to the `*`) to `Double_node<Type *>` while

```
Double_node<TType *> ptr = stack.list.head();
```

is declaring a variable `ptr` which is a `Double_node<TType *>`.

**The latter is not a pointer.**

Answer (score 2):

One of them works.

The other does not.